# eclipse - android- Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I downloaded an android project and opened it in eclipse. eclipse can not resolve R in "setContentView(R.layout.ayat)" so I guess I may have problem in "res" folder and yes!! one of my xml files in "res" folder has a big red X with "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)" message.
 I know that It means there is a compilation error in my XML file, something that shouldn't be there: a spelling mistake/a spurious character/an incorrect namespace.error but unfortunately i cant find the bad typed command.
this is the XML file:

[image: Image of my XML File]

Comment: get rid of `android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your string-array

Comment: Usually the `<resources>` tag doesn't use the `xmlns` attribute and the other attributes @Blackbelt points out. Remove it and try to clean and build your project. I copied your XML file into a project and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @BlackBelt and Darwind: Both seggestions are working. Thanks. how can I change the status of this question as solved problem?

Comment: @user2448215, I provided an answer. You can click on the checkmark

Answer (score 1):

The `<resources>` tag, and in your case the `<string-array>` tags, doesn't accept xmln attributes, such `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height`. Getting rid of them will fix your issue.